# Using yubikey for sudo

Tags: linux, security, sudo, two-factor-authentication

Is anyone successfully using [Yubikey for sudo](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-pam/)? It seems promising, but there appears to be a [weird bug](https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-pam/issues/31) which makes the setup kind or brittle. The workaround of using nscd for dns caching isn't confidence inspiring.

Answer (score 2):

I am. It works just fine on LinuxMint, following the challenge-response guide from [their website](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-pam/Authentication_Using_Challenge-Response.html). 
I did run into an issue with the lockscreen on mate because my home directory is encrypted and so my challenge file is stored in `/var/yubico` but was able to fix it by giving read rights to the mate-screensaver-dialog action using. `setcap cap_dac_read_search+eq`

Comment: Follow up, I got it working and my production deployment is still rolling to this day. My feared failure mode of losing egress or dns is less common than I feared and the minimal risk is certainly worth the added real value of a second factor for sensitive operations on critical hosts.